# How can we differentiate noise and outliers in DataMining

Tags: data-mining, data-analysis

Am unable to find out the difference between noise and outliers such that missing clarity to process data in data set.

Can anyone give a clear idea by differentiating both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Outliers are supposed to be rare.

Noise can be almost the entire data set, so something common.